# Passing an argument to Patch inside a Pytest fixture, from within a test

Tags: python, pytest

This is my fixture which returns a Foo object. I patch Foo's internal config variable, then instantiate the class with a parameter.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def foo_fix():
    patch(Foo.config, "hello"):
    def wrapper(parameter):
        return Foo(parameter=parameter)
    yield wrapper
```

In my test I do:

```
def test_foo_1(foo_fix):
    foo = foo_fix(parameter=1)
    assert foo.go() == "abc"
```

I would like to vary the Foo.config value from inside the test function. I tried nesting the foo_fix within another  function but I couldn't get it to work.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Move `patch` call inside the `wrapper` body, add another argument to `wrapper` function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@pytest.fixture
def foo_fix():
    def wrapper(parameter, config):
        patch(Foo.config, "hello"):
        return Foo(parameter=parameter)
    yield wrapper


def test_foo_1(foo_fix):
    foo = foo_fix(parameter=1, config="xyz")
    assert foo.go() == "abc"
```